# Is it an [escape-character], or is the [character-escaping]?

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags for [character-escaping](/questions/tagged/character-escaping) (*25 questions*) and [escape-character](/questions/tagged/escape-character) (*4 questions*) should be merged.

They're both fairly small tags about escaping special characters: `.` `^` `$` `*` `+` `?` `(` `)` `[` `{` `/` `\` `|` `` ` `` `"` `<` `>` and `♦`.

I see no reason not to merge them.

---

<sub>Personally, I think [escape-characters](/questions/tagged/escape-characters) should be created as a new master tag, since it's more consistent with the names for similar tags. ([tags](/questions/tagged/tags), [comments](/questions/tagged/comments), [edits](/questions/tagged/edits), [questions](/questions/tagged/questions), [answers](/questions/tagged/answers), [badges](/questions/tagged/badges), [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks), etc)</sub>